# Foundation Orbit in Vuejs 2 template

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, vue.js

I am using a foundation orbit in a vue.js 2 single file component. I got it to show but its only working for two slides yet I have four. When I load the page, it slides to the second slide automatically and stops, and it doesn't slide to any other not even the previous when I use the button. If I reload the page and I slide to another slide, lets say the last one, it stays there and refuses to slide back.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="contemporary orbit" role="region" aria-label="Contemporary Pictures" v-f-orbit>
    <ul class="orbit-container" style="height: 500px">
        <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
        <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>
        <li class="is-active orbit-slide">
    <img class="contemporary-image orbit-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg" alt="Space">
  </li>
  <li class="orbit-slide">
    <img class="contemporary-image orbit-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg" alt="Space">
  </li>
  <li class="orbit-slide">
    <img class="contemporary-image orbit-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg" alt="Space">
  </li>
  <li class="orbit-slide">
    <img class="contemporary-image orbit-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg" alt="Space">
  </li>
    </ul>
    <nav class="orbit-bullets">
        <button class="is-active" data-slide="0"><span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span><span
                class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span></button>
        <button data-slide="1"><span class="show-for-sr">Second slide details.</span></button>
        <button data-slide="2"><span class="show-for-sr">Third slide details.</span></button>
        <button data-slide="3"><span class="show-for-sr">Fourth slide details.</span></button>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9o2pmuj/)

When I inspect the code in the browser, the images that have been show have extra classes that the others:

[image: From console]

**UPDATE**
I realised that the culprit is the extra `mui` classes added to the sliders. I can't figure out what is adding them.

Comment: Are you using [mui](https://www.muicss.com) by any chance?

Comment: Nope but by default its there so I have added `data-use-m-u-i="false"` and its working.